# Backbone.js - Render a collection as HTML option tags

Tags: backbone.js

A have a collection of items I'd like to render into an existing `<select>` elment in the template. The problem I have is that the view always wraps the `<option>` list in a `DIV` tag. How can I only render the `<option>` list without any wrapping element?

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-select">
    <% _(elements).each(function(element) { %>
            <option value="<%= element.id %>"><%= element.name %></option>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

View:

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: template('template-select'),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({
                elements: this.collection.toJSON()
            }));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume somewhere else you are creating an instance of that view add rendering/adding it to the `<select>` element.

You can try something like this instead:

```
var view = new myView({el: '#id-of-existing-select'});
view.render();
```

This would make the view use the existing `<select>` instead of generating the `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem I have is that the element I want to append to dose not existi in the DOM while building the `<select>` view ... Any idea how to get around that problem?

Comment: Also have another question: If I set el, how can I render out the changes? Normally I'd do something like `$('body').append(myView.render().el)`. But If I set the el property, the changes include the complete element ...

Comment: If you set `el` you dont `append`, it is already in the DOM.  If the `<select>` is not in the DOM, [try setting tagName](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) to 'select' instead and render/append like you were.

Comment: The select is a already set in the template of another view which I then want to append the `<options>` list to. So at the moment I create the options list, the `<select>` element is not present in the DOM but only in the `el` property of another view.

Comment: Use `tagName:'select'` and remove the `<select>` from your other template. Then use something like `$('#select-container').html(myView.render().el)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I'm slowly getting to know the concept of Backbone.js.